# UnicodeDecodeError using a Python subprocess - too many commands?

Tags: python, matlab, unicode, cmd, subprocess

In a standalone python script I'm  calling a MATLAB function through a subprocess (Through the windows cmd line). The MATLAB script loads an external file into MATLAB and performs processing on the file before then saving it to a chosen destination. I'm getting the following error when run the python file:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position
>    7: ordinal not in range(128)

Here's the line that's causing the issue:

```
subprocess.call("matlab –r-nosplash -nodesktop -minimize –r filterSignal('"+fileName+"','"+directory+"','"+lowFilterNum+"','"+highFilterNum+"','"+filteredFileName+"');quit")
```

I'm aware the command argument string is very long and I guess that is the problem. Can someone maybe explain why this problem is occurring and how I can get it to work?

Comment: You've got some weird dash characters there (at `–r` for example). Try using the oldschool ascii dash `-`.

Comment: That solved it. I never would have noticed that. Much appreciated.